# Recursive function -- hooking

Tags: c, linux, hook

Suppose we have a function nammed "SomeFunction()", inside a .so.
Say this function calls itself multiple times (recursive).

Then, the following code would not work

```
main() {
     [...]
     g_backup_bytes = SetJmpHook(SomeFunction, SomeFunction_hook); // Address of func previously found using dlsym(), contained in SomeFunction
     [...]
}

void SomeFunction_hook(void)
{
     [...]
     // Do stuff here
     [...]
     // Call the real function
     UnsetJmpHook(SomeFunction, g_backup_bytes); // Restore original bytes
     SomeFunction(); // Call
     SetJmpHook(SomeFunction, SomeFunction_hook); // Restore the hook
}
```

The function I'm trying to hook, has void arguments, but modifies global variables.
I absolutely need to, each time the function is called, modify some bytes in these global variables.
Now, my problem is... when I unset the hook, like in the example above, the function calls itself, and these calls are not trapped by my SomeFunction_hook() procedure (since the jmp is not there anymore). That poses a real problem.

Do you have any ideas how I could hook every call successfully??

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you need to call it via `g_backup_bytes` rather than by the hookable entry point.  How you do that depends on how your hooking is implemented.

Comment: g_backup_bytes is just a 5 bytes struct containing the original bytes which were replaced by the jmp instruction call (which is 5 bytes). Unfortunately, they do not contain anything revelant but the start of a mov instruction (they contain a1 x x x x, i.e. mov eax, some_r/m). The function SetJmpHook() only sets a jump hook, 5 bytes long, at the function address. The UnsetJmpHook() restores the original bytes.

Comment: I mean... it sets a jump hook of the style e9 <relative_offset>, where relative offset is the result of the subtraction : SomeFunction - SomeFunction_Hook - 5
(5 being the length of the jmp instruction)

Comment: I can't find any documentation on `SetJmpHook`, is that a standard function?

Comment: Nope, its a "handcrafted" function. It really only writes a jmp at the start of the function I want to hook, to redirect to mine.